# Amazon AWS .NET/powershell scripting (new SDK)

Tags: scripting

I am trying to create an object but i am failing and i can't tell what is the problem (not a developer).

So this is part of powershell script:

```
    #AWS SDK Path 
    Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\AWS SDK for .NET\bin\Net45\AWSSDK.Core.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\AWS SDK for .NET\bin\Net45\AWSSDK.SimpleEmail.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\AWS SDK for .NET\bin\Net45\AWSSDK.EC2.dll"

    #EC2 Regions
    $serviceURL="https://ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com" # US East (Northern Virginia)

    #Global Amazon EC2 Client
    $config=New-Object Amazon.EC2.AmazonEC2Config
    $config.ServiceURL = $serviceURL
    $EC2_CLIENT=[Amazon.EC2]::AmazonEC2Client($accessKeyID, $secretAccessKey, $config)
```

Error:

```
 Unable to find type [Amazon.EC2]. Make sure that the assembly that contains this type is loaded.At line:1 char:1
    + $EC2_CLIENT=[Amazon.EC2]::AmazonEC2Client($accessKeyID, $secretAccessKey, $confi ...
    +
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Amazon.EC2:TypeName) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
```

I think i am not defining properly the assumbly but a friend opened needed DLL in Visual Studio and this is screenshot http://screencast.com/t/p5FFQCvo0B

Anyone maybe knows what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You might be able to use [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile()

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you are trying to do here but the recommended approach for using PowerShell to interact with AWS is the [AWS Tools for Windows PowerShell](https://aws.amazon.com/powershell/)

All information including downloads, tutorials and cmdlet references are available from the link above